# Character encoding issue. Single source displays multiple ways on single page

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a strange character encoding issue.

I have a page where text is pulled from my database and displayed once on the page, once in the title, and once in a jquery ui modal dialog.

The character is an n with a tilde over it. It is from the same field/column/record in the database.

On the page it is fine. In the title it appears as the diamond/question mark. In the dialog it appears as the diamond/question mark. On a previous page, (it is a CMS, so all the headers are the same) it displays, in the page, as the diamond/question mark.

So what am I missing?

Charset and collation set as UTF8 in MYSQL.

Page header is UTF8 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

I even did this in php:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Accept-Charset: utf-8');
header('Accept: text/html');

mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", "utf-8");
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "utf-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "utf-8");
```

So, I could understand if it wasn't showing right in all places, but differently on one page is messing with my *mind*.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the database connection UTF8? `SET NAMES utf8;`

Comment: Have you tried setting the client encoding using [SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)?

Comment: On the page that is messing, can you view the html source? Is there a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"`?

Comment: Hey, thank you all. I just added that to my connection script. It is now fine in the page title and the dialog, but appears as MuÃ±oz in the page body. I can't find anywhere else I am doing anything to change the encoding. To the Scrum, yes, the content type is as I have it in the question. That's how it should be, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm sort of not so bright. I being by saying that first off, adding SET NAMES fixed many problems across the board. So thank you for that. I will be putting this bit into all of my connection scripts from now on:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

I found my error was at this line:

```
echo htmlentities($person_name);
```

So, once everything was properly dispalying as utf-8, I still got the

> MuÃ±oz

because it seems that you can't convert 3 and 4 byte utf8 characters using htmlentities(). See links below.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#96648

This issue is also discussed at:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#92105

Thanks for the help all.